# flutter web alternates/reduce size of canvaskit.wasm

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, release-builds

My flutter web initial page load is slow(10-15 secs),
Found that large amount of time is spent in downloading "https://unpkg.com/canvaskit-wasm@0.24.0/bin/canvaskit.wasm" which is around 2.5 MB as per browser logs.

Is there a way to reduce this time/alternate file path/ minification which can be done?

(package is built using `flutter build web`)

Comment: I started an experimental polyfill of canvaskit that uses the browser APIs: https://github.com/wcandillon/canvaskit-lite. So far it looks promising. We test it with chrome and check that it produces the same images than the one made by CanvasKit.

Answer (score 7):

Changed web renderer to [html renderer](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers)

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html
```

which resulted in significant reduction in initial load time

Answer (score 4):

For the moment there is no solution for this, anyways the Flutter team is working on that and there should be a solution as soon as possible.
You can check the status of this in this link:
[Flutter github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76009)

Answer (score 3):

There is a possibility to integrate the canvaskit at build process and host it with your web app for offline support.

Therefore you need to define the url like:

`flutter build web --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_CANVASKIT_URL=/canvaskit/`

This may could also reduce loading time. (direct network connection, no dns lookup...)